# Anti-forgery token not loading in IIS sub-application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, antiforgerytoken

I am currently working with an asp.net core application with an Angular front end. The problem is that if I host the current website in an IIS sub-application, it does not provide an Anti-Forgery token on the initial login. If I then refresh the page, it will retrieve the token successfully. I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve the token by logging in the first time.

Hosting the website as an app works perfectly. I tried to set the path of the token to the appropriate sub-application directory, but it still does not load  initially.

> ```
>        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
>        {
>            string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
>            if (string.Equals(path, "/", >StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
>            string.Equals(path, "/publish/", >StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)|| 
>            string.Equals(path, "/index.html", >StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)||
>           string.Equals(path, "publish/", >StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
>
>           )
>            {
>                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
>                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN",
>                  tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions
>                  {
>                      HttpOnly = false,
>
>                      Path = "/publish"
>
>
>                  }
>                );
>            }
>
>            await next();
>        });
> ```
>
> I think that it should initially load with the right credentials, but I have had problems such as 400 Bad Request errors (which fix themselves after a refresh).

**Update**

I was able to get it working. I would refresh the application upon loading and this then allowed for the client to make post requests. I feel as if I am missing something obvious and would like some input on how to handle Anuglar Sub- Applications and if they require some specific routing or something else to initiate the creating of the Token.